# connect mysql database in openshift from another apllication/hosting

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, openshift

I have two application in one domain

1) In java and having phpmyadmin/mysql database.

2) In php5.3

I am try to connect first application database using second application.
but its not possible.
return error.
**Failed to connect to MySQL: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.13.153.130' (113)**

here is my code to connect phpmyadmin database.

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("127.13.153.130","adminz6RCQ***","zs4-EbW-****","testjaphp");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }else{
    echo "connected";
}
?>
```

Help me if I can do this.
thanks.

Comment: Have you checked your firewall settings so that the MySQL port is open (generally 3306)..?

Answer (score 0):

Your Java Application needs to be a scalable app so your mysql database is put on its own gear. Once its scalable it will have an externally accessible address that you can use to connect to. Simply clone your app to scalable app [see here](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/new-features-for-april-2014) and then check your environment variables to see what your new address is.